# How to use "Debug Request Flow" policy in WSO2 API Manager

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-enterprise-integrator

I try to use "Debug Request Flow" policy with a resource but i can't find logs on the file .log

logs still the same like below :

0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [30/Mar/2023:14:29:06 +0100] - 400 - - - 0.000
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [30/Mar/2023:14:29:06 +0100] GET /api/am/publisher/v3/operation-policies/2aca9f70-b362-4b24-97c6-df94e4363b27 HTTP/1.1 200 420 https://localhost:9443/publisher/apis/dce93d9f-a000-4eee-bf56-96a758808a8f/policies Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/111.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 0.106

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Did you deploy a new revision after adding the policy? The logs are added to the `wso2carbon.log` file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as @sanoJ say i was able to find the logs in the `wso2carbon.log` file .

The logs was under this format below :

```
TID: [-1234] [] [2023-04-03 13:47:04,253]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator} - {api:PizzaShackAPI:v1.0.0} To: http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous, WSAction: , SOAPAction: , MessageID: urn:uuid:70e3fac4-34b1-4cf2-b79d-48cd3d1c6ec3, correlation_id: 1aa35ee0-f2ba-4720-a0d0-673c350f4470, Direction: response, OUT_MESSAGE = OUT_MESSAGE, Payload: {"orderId":"2c2474a2-22d9-4c4e-9586-07edb9c8dd3a","pizzaType":"string","quantity":0,"customerName":"string","creditCardNumber":"string","address":"string","delivered":true}
```